# JavaScript, как добавить класс элементу полученным getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как добавить класс элементу полученным `getElementsByClassName`? пробовал `elem.classList.add('class')`; -- не получается((
Причём если получать элемент по ID (`getElementById`) то класс добавляется и всё работает.
Подскажите в чём проблема?

```
html

<div class = "blocks">
    <div class = "firstBlock" onclick="showSecondBlock();">
        <div class = "secondBlock"></div>
    </div>                              
</div>  

 css

.secondBlock {display: none;}
.show {display: block;}

js
function showSecondBlock() {

var block = document.getElementsByClassName('secondBlock');
block.classList.add('show');
}
```

Comment: Почему не используешь jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, что функция с названием

*getElement**S**......* (взять элемен**ТЫ**)

возвращает не один элемент, а **коллекцию**. Даже если этот элемент один на странице. Следовательно, нужно брать индекс этого элемента и уже к нему применять изменения. Если элемент один, то брать элемент с индексом 0.

```
block[0].classList.add('show');
```